# Uploading Images and how to get that image inside the SQL using GROUP by and MAX()

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE accountID = '{$accID}' GROUP BY album_name ORDER BY photo_number DESC");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
        echo "<div class=\"myPhotos\"><img title='Album: {$row['album_name']}' src=\"images/profile/".$row['photo_link']."\"/></div>";
    }
}else{
    echo "No Album Created";
}
```

My Intension: is to get the HIGHER 'photo_number' value, while I am also grouping them by their own respective 'album_name' however my $result cant recognize the TOP/HIGHER 'photo_number'(AUTO INCREMENT attribute) how could I recognize the HIGHER 'photo_number' ?

they said that I need to use MAX(photo_number) but, how to code that MAX() syntax?...I hope that you can help me in this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't perfectly clear but I guess you want the highest photo number for each album name and then to sort by that number. If that's the case you'll want something like...

```
SELECT album_name,
       MAX(photo_number) AS highest_photo_number
    FROM photos
    WHERE accountID = (whatever)
    GROUP BY album_name
    ORDER BY highest_photo_number;
```

Comment: the SQL code is working, but how can I print the album_name using the highest_photo_number? maybe using IF STATEMENT?...but how?

Comment: @ChowKiko, on select statement add photo id In case you need later more info about certain photo. I recommended just grab info from database as arrays and if needed additional modifications make it with PHP.

Comment: @xeranas, @ChowKiko, if you use a `GROUP BY` clause, you can't then rely on any column you select that isn't mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause, unless it is an aggregate of some sort. The `GROUP BY album_name` clause will roll up all the rows with the same album name together; putting a column `photo_id` in the `SELECT` list would have no meaning. I'm not sure what you mean by 'print the album name using the highest_photo_number. Perhaps you could expand on that a little?

Comment: I want to use the features of Facebook, wherein IF THE USER UPLOADS a photo with in an ALBUM, the ALBUM itself changes its primary picture thats why I am also using the photo_number where I will check the HIGHEST value of it, also sorting those album_name.....My point here is that THE USER UPLOADS A PHOTO, the PHOTO ITSELF MUST RELY ON THE ALBUM, THEN THE ALBUM UPDATES IT SELF USING THE MOST TOP VALUE OF photo_number, your CODE above is now working, and now its 100% working, I can UPLOAD a photo, access my album and I can see the updated photos ^_^

Comment: @ChowKiko, I'm sorry, I can't help you there: I know nothing whatever about Facebook.